# Configuring spring repository in different spring boot starter

Tags: java, spring

I decided that i will split spring boot application into smaller pieces. One of those pieces was spring repository (models as entities). I decided that it will be done using autoconfiguration. so if i will attach that starter/dependency to project database with proper tables will be created automatically.

Before changes whole project was working fine.

So i moved my models to that new repository starter (They have entity annotation).

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account implements Serializable {
```

I created spring.factories and placed it in proper place with proper values

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.application.RepositoryAutoconfiguration
```

The autoconfiguration class looks following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.application.model"})
public class RepositoryAutoconfiguration {
}
```

I thought if i will do like that then entities will be created automatically in database.

So i attached that newly built depednecny to my main project and when i started that app i recievied:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.application.model.Account
```

It looks like it is not working.

Do you have any hints how to handle that case ? I checked the stackoverlow and i could notice like in some cases the issue was connected with missing entity annotation, but it is not my case.

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: You probably need `@EntityScan` and perhaps `@EnableJpaRepositories` instead of `@ComponentScan`